# Sign Up For Newsletter checkbox in guest checkout?

Tags: magento2, newsletter, guest-checkout

I'm looking for a way to get a Newsletter Signup checkbox in Magento 2 onestep  guest checkout, just the same way it is when you create a new account. What is the easiest way to do this? 
Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is a free module available called Subscribe at Checkout:

https://marketplace.magento.com/mageside-module-subscribe-at-checkout.html

Comment: Does this work with the Ebizmarts Mailchimp extension?

Comment: @PrimalSpace I don't know, I have not tried that.